# How Call 2 External API parallel and perform merge once both response are received in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rest, spring-boot

I have a small requirement, where I will have a Unique ID.

Using this ID I need to perform a Rest GET Call to 2 different system say System 1 and System 2, which will return me the 2 JSON Payload from different System.

After that once JSON Payload is received I need to merge if there exist any change in payload from system 1.

I just wanted to know is there any Spring Boot Capability which I can use to complete this Task, My main requirement is

1: Both GET Request to system 1 and system 2 should go parallel.

2: Perform merging and comparing of payload only once I receive Response from both the System.

Please suggest if you have some good reference or template that I can use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `@Async` to a method and `@EnableAsync` in configuration class. Learn on CompletableFuture interface

Comment: Can you please suggest what is actually use of @Async here I want both call to be synchronous which means when response for both the call are received only then I will proceed ahead for merge.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use completeable feature interface for both api calls. Code inside this interface will run async. Below is the sample code for it.

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<String>() {
@Override
public String get() {
    try {
        //api call1
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    return "Result of the asynchronous computation";
}
```

});

```
CompletableFuture<String> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<String>() {
@Override
public String get() {
    try {
        //api call2
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    return "Result of the asynchronous computation";
}
```

});

```
String result1 = future1.get();
String result2 = future2.get();
```

Comment: This example does not cover his second point: `2: Perform merging and comparing of payload only once I receive Response from both the System.`

Comment: Hello @PawełGłowacz do I need to perform something like CompletableFuture.allOf(future1 ,future2).join(); To make them dependent on each other ?

Comment: @HargunSuri `CompletableFuture.allOf().join()` returns a CompletableFuture that is completed when all the given futures complete. So if you want compare each payload you need to wait till all futures will be completed.